# How can I combine/merge the daily precipitation barplot with the mean daily precipitation line plot?

Tags: r

Here are my barplot for the daily precipitation:

```
barplot(floods, col="black", ylim=c(0,300),border=NA,cex.axis=0.9,      cex.main=1.1,cex.names=0.9,cex.lab=1, space=c(2),xlab="June", las=1,tck=0.01, ylab="mm/day", 
      names.arg=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"))


box()
ticks=c(1:29)
axis(side=1, tck=0.01, labels=NA)
axis(side=2, tck=0.01, labels=NA)


grid(NA, 6, lwd = 1.5, col="gray60")

barplot(floods, col="black", ylim=c(0,50),border=NA,cex.axis=0.9, ,cex.main=1.1,cex.names=0.9,cex.lab=1, space=c(2),xlab="June", las=1,tck=0.01, ylab="mm/day",
    add=T)
```

I would like to add these line plot with mean dailiy precipitation data...

```
plot(c(1,30),c(0,300), type="n", border=NA,cex.axis=0.75,  cex.main=1.1,cex.names=0.75,cex.lab=0.8,main="Mean Daily Precipitation Dehradun (1980-2014)",xlab="June", ylab="mm/day")

lines(temp.india$day, temp.india$rain, col="black", lty=1, lwd=2)
```

Comment: Please make your code [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), for instance by providing part of the data with `dput(head(floods,10))`

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data? C.f., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I have a list with the days (1.6. - 30.6) and corresponding rain amount. e.g. day 1 with 16.557 mm rain...

Comment: > dput(head(floods,10))
c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6.1, 0, 4.1, 6.1, 0)

Comment: Here are the daily temp. data: dput(head(floods, 30))
c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6.1, 0, 4.1, 6.1, 0, 57.9, 1, 7.1, 93, 54.1, 
220, 0, 11.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 47, 30, 119.9, 0.3, 7.1, 23.9, 8.9, 
23.9)

Comment: Please edit your original question. Make it so that one can copy/paste the code into his or her R session and pick up where you left off.